# Hide div when scrolled to specific anchor points using Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I plan to use the fantastic Fullpage.js from http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ but would like to hide specific divs or images when scrolled to a specific anchor point.

For example if the page starts at #home & has 3 anchor points (full screen sections) #home, #biog & #email all with a logo at the top of each section i would like for instance for the logo from #biog to hide (perhaps with fade out) but reshow (perhaps with fade in) when scrolled to the next anchor point #email

Can this be done?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: yes, it can be done. but first show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do it is using fullPage events. In this case: `afterLoad` or `onLeave`
[Take a look at the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) for more information about how to use them.

You can take a look at this living example in which the top menu fades In or out depending on whether the user is in the first section or not:
http://jsfiddle.net/J8hqM/8/

It should look like:

```
  // Script FullPage
  $.fn.fullpage({
      /* whatever config you have...*/
      afterLoad: function(anchor, index){
          if(index == 1){
               $('#menu').fadeOut();
          }else{
               $('#menu').fadeIn();   
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. Would this still work with the 'fixed header & footer' version? Could i say for example make the footer fade out when scrolled to #biog (section 2) but fade back in again when scrolled to #email (section 3)?

Comment: Yeah, with anything you want, why not?

Comment: Would you be kinda enough to show me how i would go about doing this please?

Comment: I've already told you how to do it. What else do you need? Look at the code I posted as well as the living example code. If you don't give me your website URL I can not be more specific.

Comment: Please excuse me as I'm still not able to make this work but really appreciate you talking the time to help.

Here is what i am trying to hide on #anchor2 when scrolled to but show on #anchor3 when scrolled to...

http://jsfiddle.net/4XYJC/4/


Could you show me how your example would work with this Div?

Comment: Here is a cleaner comment with link to the div footer i am trying to hide: http://jsfiddle.net/4XYJC/4/

Comment: I can not see anything in that jsfiddle, just the credits `div` and some css... Did you saved it correctly? You have to click on "update".

Comment: Really? As i can see it here, it was just to show you the code of the fixed footer div i would like to hide & reshow. If you can see the Div & CSS then you can see what I'm trying to hide. As a better example can we refer to your fixed header & footer demo from your website here: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html#secondPage


Using your demo how would i hide the footer at the bottom of the page when scrolled to #secondPage but reshow when scrolled to #3rdPage ?

Hope that makes things clearer & thank you for talking the time to help me

Comment: @markkane, I don't know what else you want to know. I have already told you how to do it. Using the `afterLoad` and when the index is equal to the section index you want, then do whatever. I already gave you this example, please, take a look at it and try to understand how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/J8hqM/8/

Comment: Thank you so much, your script was 100% correct! I had a line of extra code i did not spot until looking at it for the 100th time hahaha. Sorry for all the hassle but i really appreciate it ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You could use jquery's `$(window).bind( 'hashchange'` function.

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function() {
    var winloc = window.location.href;
    if (winloc.substring(1) === "Yourpage") {
    //do something. For example:
    $("#Yourlogo").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much but see below for my problem with this....

Would this still work with the 'fixed header & footer' version? Could i say for example make the footer fade out when scrolled to #biog (section 2) but fade back in again when scrolled to #email (section 3)?

Comment: @markkane, this is not the perfect solution. You can run fullpage.js without anchors or running it with anchors, you may have section which anchors would look like `#sectionName/slideName`